# VueJS how to access a value in an array in JSON output of API call?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm doing a blog from scratch with a front and backend that communicates via an API I made, here's the JSON output:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "a la zeub",
            "description": "zebi",
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-12-08T12:16:58.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-12-08T12:16:58.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "title2",
            "description": "thing",
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-12-08T12:39:15.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-12-08T12:39:15.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use VueJS as a frontend, when I want to display one value of the API response I use this syntax in the HTML part:

```
<p> {{ the name of the variable }} </p>
```

But it doesn't work, if I do this:

```
<p> {{ posts.status }} </p>
```

it returns "true" in the `p` tag, but if I try something like `posts.posts.id` or `posts.posts['id']` it doesn't work at all, the `p` tag is present in the source code but without content. What should I write between the brackets to access the title?

Comment: its an array you need to loop it with v-for, to access the first item its `{{ posts.posts[0].id }}`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hello! First, thank you for answering, but it's still not working... here's what I did:

<div v-for="posts in posts" :key="posts.posts[0].id">
    <p v-html="posts.posts[0].id"></p>
  </div>

Comment: yeah do like `<div v-for="item in posts.posts" :key="item.id"> <p>{{ item.id }}</p> </div>`, notice posts is item `posts in posts` wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @LawrenceCherone and pursuing the comments, you need to do something like this-

To prepare an example, I take a variable `posts` in the `data` property and assign your JSON output to it.

```html
<html>
<div id="app">
  <p v-for="(post, index) in posts.posts" :key="index">{{ post.title }}</p>
</div>

<!-- Don't forget to include Vue from CDN! -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app', //Tells Vue to render in HTML element with id "app"
    data() {
      return {
        posts: {
         status: true,
         posts: [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "a la zeub",
            "description": "zebi",
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-12-08T12:16:58.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-12-08T12:16:58.000000Z"
           },
           {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "title2",
            "description": "thing",
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-12-08T12:39:15.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-12-08T12:39:15.000000Z"
            }
         ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```